# Error C2259 cannot instantiate abstract class

Tags: c++

I am a beginner in C++. Taking first course in college. I am trying to make ordered linked list class, I do the same way like in the book, but still have an error. Could you please help me to solve this problem.
Error C2259 cannot instantiate abstract class.

Visual Studio 2017.

Header file ListType

```
#ifndef H_ListType
#define H_ListType

template <class Type>
class linkedListType
{
public:
    virtual void inserFirst(const Type& newItem) = 0;

    ~linkedListType();
};
#endif
```

header file ordered.h

```
#ifndef H_ordered
#define H_ordered
#include "ListType.h"

template <class Type>
class orderedLinkedList : public linkedListType<Type>
{
public: 
    void insertFirst(const Type& newItem);
};

    template <class Type>
    void orderedLinkedList<Type>::insertFirst(const Type& newItem)
    {
        ; // NOP
    }

#endif
```

main source file

```
#include "ordered.h"
#include "ListType.h"


void main()
{
    orderedLinkedList<int> List1;

    _getwch();
}
```

Comment: This is _way_ more code than needs to be shown.

Comment: Since I already voted to close as a typo, I'm going to edit this question down to the MCVE you should aim to post in the first place.

Answer (score 4):

You may reasonably have intended the second of these methods to override the first:

```
virtual void linkedListType::inserFirst(const Type& newItem) = 0;
        void orderedLinkedList::insertFirst(const Type& newItem)
```

but unfortunately you have a spelling mistake - `inserFirst` is *not* the same function as `insertFirst`.

This is the problem the [`override`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/override) specifier is designed to solve.

Comment: Thanks, I fixed misspelled name but new I have some others mistakes.

Comment: Error C2065 'first': undeclared identifier  ordered.h

Comment: Error C2065 'last': undeclared identifier ordered.h

Comment: Error C2227 left of '->link' must point to class/struct/union/generic type ordered.h 125

Comment: Congratulations, those bugs deserve their own questions. Please post a _minimal_ complete example with them.